# ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier function availableToWithdraw(address walletAddress) public returns(bool)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, public, remix

Im following a youtube tutorial on smart contracts as i am still very new to solidity however when I compile I am getting this error.

ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
--> contracts/CryptoKids.sol:57:14:
|
57 |     function availableToWithdraw(address walletAddress) public returns(bool)
|              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicensed
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract CryptoKids
{
    //Define Dad
    address owner;

    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    //Define Kid
    struct Kid{
        address payable walletAddress;
        string firstName;
        string LastName;
        uint releaseTime;
        uint amount;
        bool canWithdraw;
    }

    Kid[] public kids;

    //add kid to contract
    function addKids(address payable walletAddress,string memory firstName,string memory LastName,uint releaseTime,uint amount,bool canWithdraw) public{
        kids.push(Kid(walletAddress,firstName,LastName,releaseTime,amount,canWithdraw));
    }

    //deposit funds to contract, specifically to kids contract
    function deposit(address walletAddress) payable public {
        addToKidsBalance(walletAddress);
    }

    function balanceOf() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function addToKidsBalance(address walletAddress) private{
        for (uint i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
            if(kids[i].walletAddress == walletAddress){
                kids[i].amount += msg.value;
            }
        }
    }

    function getIndex(address walletAddress) view private returns(uint){
        for (uint i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
            if(kids[i].walletAddress == walletAddress){{
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 999;
    }

    //kid checks if can withdraw
    function availableToWithdraw(address walletAddress) public returns(bool)
    {
        uint i = getIndex(walletAddress);
        if (block.timestamp > kids[1].releaseTime)
        {
            kids[i].canWithdraw = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //if can withdraw money
    function withdraw(address payable walletAddress) payable public{
        uint i = getIndex(walletAddress);
        kids[i].walletAddress.transfer(kids[i].amount);
    }
    
}
```

Im not sure what the issue is as ive checked my codes with against the video that im following and cant find anything wrong
Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9MVkHKV2Vw

Answer (score 0):

In your `getIndex()` function remove a curly bracket in the end of the following `if condition`:

```
function getIndex(address walletAddress) view private returns(uint){
  for (uint i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
    if(kids[i].walletAddress == walletAddress){{ // <- This is the issue
      return i;
    }
  }
 return 999;
}
```

Replace it with:

```
function getIndex(address walletAddress) view private returns(uint){
  for (uint i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
    if(kids[i].walletAddress == walletAddress) {
      return i;
    }
  }
 return 999;
}
```